# What $U(P_n,f)-L(P_n,f)\rightarrow 0$ means for $f$ $?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$  is  bounded  and  there  is a  sequence $\{P_n\}$  of  partitions  s.t. $$U(P_n,f)-L(P_n,f)\rightarrow 0$$ .  Then  prove  that $f$ is  integrable .

Geometrically  , I can  visualize  the  difference  between  the  *lower sum* and  the  *upper sum*  vanishes  eventually  and  hence  the  are  equal  resulting  in  $f$  being  integrable.  But  I  cannot  find  a  way  to  prove  it  analytically.

Please  help  with  that .  Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition for $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Xiao :  $f$  is  $\mathcal R$-integrable  if $\exists$  a  real  number  $A$  s.t.  for  any  $\epsilon \gt 0$  $\exists$  a  partition  $P$ such  that   for  any  refinement   $Q$  of  $P$  $|S(Q,f)-A|\lt \epsilon $ . This  is  the  definition  I  read.

Comment: Every Riemann sum is sandwiched between those two, so it must converge to some limit.

Comment: What is the connection between refinement of partition $P$, call this $Q$ for $U(P,f), U(Q,f)$ and $L(P,f), L(Q,f)$?

Comment: @Xiao : $L(p.f)\le L(Q,f)\le U(Q,f)\le U(P,f)$ . And  $S(Q,f)$  will  fit  in  between  like $L(p.f)\le L(Q,f)\le S(Q,f)\le  U(Q,f)\le U(P,f)$

Answer (score 0):

We can define $A = \inf_P U(P, f)$.  From the assumption of your problem, for each $\epsilon$, you can find a $P_N$ such that $$U(P_N, f) - L(P_N,f) \leq \epsilon. \quad \quad (\star)$$
Continue from your remark, we have
$$ L(P_N,f) -A \leq S(P_N, f) -  A \leq U(P_N, f) - A.$$
From $(\star)$,
$$ U(P_N, f) - A \leq U(P_N, f) - L(P_N,f) \leq \epsilon$$
and 
$$L(P_N,f) -A \geq L(P_N,f) - U(P_N, f) \geq -\epsilon,$$
therefore 
$$-\epsilon \leq S(P_N, f) -  A \leq \epsilon.$$
Now show this also holds for any refinement of $P_N$.

Comment: How  did  you  get  $U(P_N,f)-A     \le U(P_N,f)-L(P_N,f)$  from  $\star $  $?$

Comment: This is because lower sum is always less than or equal to upper sum, thus lower sum is also less than or equal to the inf of upper sum.